# Load view from IB without showing to user

Tags: swift, ios8, storyboard

Probably a bit hard to explain without diagrams but here goes.

Swift, iOS 8 using Storyboards.

I want to be able to load a view in the storyboard, load values into textfields, populate the TableView, etc. as if I was navigating to it normally but not actually showing the view to the user.

The view is an invoice template that I can capture and turn into a PDF but that relies on the fact that the view is populated with values, i.e. Loading the view.

I can call the PDF capture function without going to the view but the view is empty of values and table data. So far I've tried :-

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("orderform") as OrderForm
   vc.createPDFfromUIView(vc.view, aFilename: "test.pdf")
```

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
vc.view.hidden = true
```

before you present it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in the end. I had to move code that was in

> viewDidLoad

to

> ViewDidLayoutSubviews

on the OrderForm for the view to complete before taking a snap shot. Then the code below worked.

> ```
>     // Instatiate OrderForm viewController
>     let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("orderform") 
>     as OrderForm
>
>     // Copy arrray items to OrderForm viewController for tableView data
>     vc.Orders = Orders
>
>     // Create PDF of OrderForm view using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
>     vc.createPDFfromUIView(vc.view, aFilename: "\(companyTextField.text).pdf")
>
>     // Call UIActivityViewController and attach PDF
>     share(sender)
> ```

Thanks,
Anthony